# TypeScript Exclude<UnionOfTypes, Interface> is type "never"

Tags: typescript, typing, union-types

Why in the following code is `Exclude<A,B>` resolving to the `never` type? Can't the typescript compiler know (through static analysis) that `A` and `B` extend `Parent` and thus `Exclude<Choices, Parent>` should resolve to type `C`?

```js
interface Parent {}

interface A extends Parent {}
interface B extends Parent {}
interface C {}

type Choices = A | B | C

type Test = Exclude<Choices, Parent> // = type "never"???

const c: C = {}
const d: Test = c // Type 'C' is not assignable to type 'never'
```

I could hard code `Parent = A | B` but I'm unsure why I need to.

Comment: One thing I realized is that you could define `interface Parent { readonly Parent: unique symbol }` and prevent the duck typing issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because TypeScript has duck typing. Specifically, since `C` and `Parent` are the same interface, `C` is assignable to `Parent`.

Specifically, this compiles:

```
const c: C = {};
const p: Parent = c;
```

So, although `C` doesn't explicitly `extend Parent`, TypeScript still says that `C` is a `Parent`.

If you want this to work, just add something to `Parent` that `C` doesn't have.

```
interface Parent { foo: string }

interface A extends Parent {}
interface B extends Parent {}
interface C {}

type Choices = A | B | C

type Test = Exclude<Choices, Parent> // = type C

const c: C = {}
const d: Test = c // works!
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a type tool as follows

```
// It is the opposite operation to [exclude].
type Has<T, U> = U extends T ? U : never;
```

Usage is as follows

```
    type A = {
      a : number;
      aa:number;
      aaa:number;
    }

    type B = {
      b : number;
    }

    type C = {
      c : number;
    }

    type D = {
      d : number;
    }


    // Here means the type A
    type Node_HasA = Has<{
      a : number;
    }, A|B|C|D>
```